# Pictometry Accuracy and/or Alternative

Tags: 3d, imagery, pictometry

I'm looking for some insights into the accuracy (x,y,z) of oblique imagery from Pictometry in terms of providing accurate measurements for property evaluation. Is the high cost of this product justified by its potential to provide not only high visual/pixel resolution, but also highly accurate measurements? Essentially, I'm curious about alternatives that are more cost effective and provide equal or better accuracy in the 2-D plane.

I find a lot of sales/marketing info from Pictometry, but not much quantitative metadata in terms of consistency for what DTMs they use to rectify the images. There seems to be a lot of momentum behind this company and I want to know if it's justified.

Comment: Please follow the links below for more information: http://www.pictometry.com/docs/Absolute%20Horizontal%20Accuracies_2013-03-21.pdf and http://www.pictometry.com/docs/RelativeMeasurementAccuracies_2012-05-24.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I think a LOT depends on what you need that level of accuracy for.  If you have a project involving only a few buildings, it would probably be cheaper to buy a hypsometer and go and measure the heights yourself armed with a camera!  For a really serious project where mm accuracy is essential and mission-critical, you will do better to get a trained surveyor to measure the buildings for you rather than pictometry (in my opinion).  For less serious projects, you should be able to extract heights from high quality Lidar data for larger volumes of buildings... and so not need pictometry.

Pictometry has its place but there are plenty of alternatives.  While I have seen a lot of hype about it, I've never personally found a need for it as the cost has always been prohibitive... unless you're Google, building a 3D web-app of course :)

Answer (score 2):

I manage a roofing company in Philadelphia. Pictometry is extremely useful, albeit expensive. It does have a learning curve, but not one too steep that I had trouble training my staff.

The biggest limitation is in areas with large buildings. Often buildings are obscured by other structures, so it makes pitch measurements all but impossible.

Honestly it is worth the money for someone in my business, because we use it on a daily basis, but for someone who won't need the amount of measurements we need would be spending way too much.

As a side note the images come from Bing I'm pretty sure, so if that's all you need, save your money.

I would love to know if there are open source alternatives.... But as far as I know none exist.