# Looking for GIS server for Pictometry that can do Bing-like "birds eye" tilted view and rotation

Tags: web-service, imagery, pictometry

I need an open source GIS server that can present these Pictometry images, I guess they are also called 2.5-D. The camera on a plane takes 5 shots, one orthogonal, other 4 in all directions. North, west...

2.5-D images are the main focus here, user would have to be able to rotate the tilted view in 4 directions. Additionally I would like to have those standard GIS server features like vector layers, queries, labels, redlining...

So far I have decent experience with MapGuide, open source and the the Autodesk one, and I can't recall those features. No rotation or tilting at all, I might be wrong. I have very basic XP with GeoServer and MapServer.

I'm looking for advice in which direction to go with research. I was thinking GeoServer is the best bet, but what interface...

Also, I can't really say that I've been working with any kind of 3-D desktop GIS. I would take some advice on that too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to focus it more, please?  If serving 2.5D images is the most important requirement then focus on that and include the research you have done so far into possible candidates and why you may already have excluded them.

Comment: Sure, I'll try.

Comment: This is quite important to me. I need to start exploring possibilities asap. Pls tell me if there is still something wrong with my question. I don't know, maybe the 3d desktop question is too in the same thread, i figure they are related enough. Thx.

Comment: There is an answer that mentions some of the same requirements at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60876/pictometry-accuracy-and-or-alternative

Comment: Thx, at least now I know the correct term.

Comment: I also just found out that pictometry technology is copyrighted by some company in NY, so I guess there is little chance to have it in some open source gis atm. This is valuable knowledge to me too, I have something to report. I guess our client has to be informed about what server to use... because he has that license. Keep the thread open pls and thx again.